# How many fireplaces are needed for incubation?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Okay, so on ark I recently decided to start breeding my raptor. I had to find her the perfect raptor. After 8 hours of searching I find the desired stud raptor. He is a hulking level 124 male raptor with the coolest coloration I have seen yet. I tranqed him and tamed him. After dropping him off in the raptor stabbing cabin they got down and dirty. Fifteen minutes later and the egg is laid. I place five campfires down but nothing happened. I lost the egg and now I am frustrated. How many campfires do I need? How do I incubate this egg?

Comment: And no I am doing this without air conditioners on the center map. I'm not spending my resources to build AC units and all the unnecessary electrics to run them unless there is no other way. I don't care how long it takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:
How many fireplaces are needed for incubation - Different amounts for different animals

How many fireplaces for a Raptor:

> INCUBATING THE EGG: The fertilized egg  will only make incubation progress when on the ground (not when in any inventory) and when maintained at the correct temperature. If the egg is on the ground and it is too hot or too cold, it will lose health over time. The egg will NOT lose health in the player's inventory so you can save an egg from bad weather by picking it up and holding it until the temperature is more aggreeable. The incubation temperature range for a raptor egg is 20-27 degrees Celsius (68-82 degrees Faranheit). The egg is too cold at 19 degrees below, and too hot at 28 degrees and above.

The see the Wiki for the [incubation guide](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Raptor#Breeding) for the Raptor.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal situation you only need 1 fireplace. Each type of egg has its own temperature requirements.

From the wiki on [incubation](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Incubation), raptor eggs need to be kept between 20 and 28 degrees Celsius. Fortunately, this includes room temperature, so under favorable conditions, a shelter may be enough to provide enough warmth. The way [temperature](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Temperature) works in Ark, the distance of the heat sources matter. You can use your character screen to find the temperature of your current position. After placing a fireplace in a building walk around until you find a spot that is within the range for the egg. Then simply set the egg down. You might need more than one fireplace if you are in a colder biome.

If the temperature is above the range for your egg, you will not be able to incubate without an air conditioner.

Raptor Incubation Table
[image]

Checking Temperature
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Take any type of egg, and place it in the middle of 4 campfires in a warm house. Place the campfires like a square, and then light the fires. Put as much wood or flint as possible.

As you look at the egg it will say incubation 100%, and it will slowly go down. Eventually it will hatch, but you have to watch it.

Comment: Consider skimming through this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: Hi max, I have edited your answer for you. We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it. You also might want to check out [this help article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).